# Can username password flow be used to access inbox on exchange using EWS?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

My goal is to  access the inbox to  download emails.I did some research and found that UsernamePassowrdflow will fit in my requirement.

But not sure what permissions can be given to the application created on Azure AD.Also, If I  acquire a token using this flow can  this be used in java EWS?

Comment: I  have accessed inbox using ClientCredentialGrant flow. But this requires full_access of mail boxes, which is a security concern. So, can  we do using username-pasword flow?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you could use UsernamePassowrdflow ([ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc)). But the permissions are the same as [Auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow).

Please refer to [Scoping application permissions to specific Exchange Online mailboxes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access?view=graph-rest-1.0), which can limit your application to only access to the specified mailboxes.

Just use the `New-ApplicationAccessPolicy` PowerShell cmdlet to configure access control.

```
New-ApplicationAccessPolicy -AppId e7e4dbfc-046f-4074-9b3b-2ae8f144f59b -PolicyScopeGroupId EvenUsers@contoso.com -AccessRight RestrictAccess -Description "Restrict this app to members of distribution group EvenUsers."
```

Comment: I used ClientCredentialGrant and gave permission of full access to all mail boxes using EWS. In  addition I applied  Scoping application permissions to specific Exchange Online mailboxes. But still it is not restricting to  specific inbox.

Comment: Looks like its bug. In microsoft Oauth thing